# LCD image is fuzzy when connected via analog connection instead of digital

Tags: graphics, lcd, vga, dvi

I have GeForce 660 Ti and a 1680x1050 LCD. Unfortunately [I am forced](https://superuser.com/questions/496136/screen-occasionally-flashes-black) to connect the LCD to the graphics card via analog connection (VGA cable + VGA-to-DVI-A adapter), instead of digital.

The resulting image is a bit fuzzy (though sometimes it gets sharper for a second or so).

What is the cause of this? Is there any way to solve it? Perhaps I need a different VGA cable or a VGA-to-DVI-I adapter? Or is it some inherent limitation of my setup?

The monitor is LG L226WTQ-BF; according to its specification it can support its native 1680x1050 resolution on analog connection.

Comment: What is a *" VGA-to-DVI-A adapter"*?  Or do you really mean a DVI-I-to-VGA adapter?  (The data flow is from source to destination.)  What is the manufacturer & model of this monitor?  What is its native resolution?  Does the manual describe restrictions on the VGA resolutions?  Have you tried different resolutions besides 1680x1050?

Comment: @sawdust updated question with monitor make and model. The resolution in question is the native resolution, otherwise I wouldn't have bothered asking this question, as I would have expected fuzziness. The same reason is why I haven't tried other resolutions. Regarding the adapter, I'm used to referring to adapters by from-socket-to-socket (female-to-male), regardless of the data flow direction; but of course in this case the video output from the card is via DVI socket and then it is adapted to the socket the analog cable expects, with the adapter.

Comment: It could just be a low quality VGA cable or a low quality adapter. Have you tried a different cable and adapter?

Comment: Since it's not a scaling issue, then the next likely issue is the VGA cable.  For high-res VGA, high-end and professional/industrial display devices (e.g. CRT monitors and projectors, I have both) use BNCs instead of inferior HD15 connector (it's simply not a 75 Ohm connector like BNC).  For a high quality VGA cable look [here](http://www.bluejeanscable.com/store/rgbhv/index.htm).

Comment: Search the web for either the Nokia or Eizo monitor tests.  The Nokia program has a few more patterns useful for CRT alignment/convergence, but only the Eizo program runs in Win 64-bit mode.  There's full-resolution test patterns of alternating dark/black & white lines.  The screen will look like a light grey, but you should still make out individual lines when viewed close up.  Try comparing the VGA connection versus the DVI using these test patterns, and come up with better descriptions than "fuzzy".

Comment: @Cry I honestly didn't realize that relatively-short VGA cables come in different qualities. I changed to another cable and it solved the problem :) I'll upvote an answer if you'll post one!

Comment: @sawdust see my comment above to Cry Havok; using a different cable solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may simply be a cable quality issue. I've had that before where low quality cables have resulted in a fuzzy display. Try swapping the cable for one you know to be ok.